# Google Fonts Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to find an example of using google fonts in Marketing-Cloud, here's what I currently have but it seems that the platform(Marketing-Cloud) is stripping out this code while rendering of all emails.  Does Marketing-Cloud allow google fonts to be implemented?

```
    /*================================================================================
      Lora == https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700&display=swap"%20rel="stylesheet
==================================================================================*/
@media screen {
    /* latin */
    /* latin-ext */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Lora';
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-display: swap;
      src: local('Lora Italic'), local('Lora-Italic'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lora/v14/0QIhMX1D_JOuMw_LL_tLtfOm84TX.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
    }
    /* cyrillic-ext */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Lora';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      src: local('Lora Bold'), local('Lora-Bold'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lora/v14/0QIgMX1D_JOuO7HeNtFumtus-7zu-Q.woff2) format('woff2');
      unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using templates or paste html?

Comment: @KyleSzabo I'm using paste html